# Shorter way of specifying HTML 4.01 Strict

Tags: html, doctype

I am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

in my web pages.

I remember reading in one of those XHTML vs HTML questions that one of the (small) advantages of using HTML is, a shorter DOCTYPE like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Can I use some shorter version like that and specify HTML 4.01 Strict?

If I simply use the short version, what will it be taken as? - Strict, Transitional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, if there were a shorter version we would all be using it. :) The short type you are referring to is [HTML 5](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/).

Comment: Oh! Isn't there no strict, frameset or transitional versions in HTML 5?

Comment: Nope.  HTML 5 does away with that complexity.  Of course it's also not truly a finished spec at the moment, so maybe if we're unlucky we'll get those in the future.

Comment: HTML5 doesn't specify DTD or any other form of validation as part of the spec. What conformance checkers exist (and as ShZ said, we're far from having a locked-down language at this point) are unofficial ad-hoc analysis tools. As such the phrase “valid HTML5” may be essentially meaningless.

Comment: bobince: that's just FUD. HTML5 explicitly defines conformance criteria for conformance checkers / validators. See http://www.whatwg.org/html5/#conformance-checkers . validator.nu and validator.w3.org are excellent tools already.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. I'm afraid that's the only way to specify using `HTML 4.01 Strict.`

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there's a shorter way of specifying a HTML 4.0 Strict Doctype, which is a pretty specific document type. The doctype you gave would be valid for HTML 5, which may well be a good choice for a new site anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply leave of the URL, and use just the public identifier, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
```

This will validate as HTML 4.01 Strict, and trigger standards mode.  The short DOCTYPE is also valid for HTML 4.01 Transitional, but will trigger quirks mode in some browsers.  Keep in mind, though, that this is **strictly forbidden** in XHTML.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your HTML to be validated you will **at least** need to specify an (url to) a DTD...

I think you maybe could leave out the public name, maybe be changing the keyword PUBLIC to SYSTEM. But i'm not quite sure about this...

**EDIT**: Why is this voted down?? The question was for HTML 4, **not for 5**...

Comment: So, even in HTML 5, for it to be validated by tools such as W3 validator, it needs to have a DTD url?

Comment: senthil: Nope. HTML5 isn't that insane.